# Trying to make a ball bounce on the screen in processing using classes

Tags: processing

I am working on making a single ball bounce all over the screen but I have an issue with making the ball bounce the bounce() function is responsible for making the ball bounce but I run into an array out of bounds exception despite only going through 1 element in the array. I have provided the code below. This code utilizes 2 classes (Ball_Usage and Ball).

Ball_Usage code:

```
Ball ball1;

    void setup(){
     size(500,500);
     
     ball1 = new Ball();
     
    }
    
    void draw(){
     background(255);
     ball1.bounce();
    }
```

Ball:

```
class Ball{
 float [] xPos = {};
 float [] yPos = {};
 float [] dia = {};
 float [] xSpeed = {};
 float [] ySpeed = {};
 
 Ball(){
   
   }
   
   Ball(float x, float y, float argDia){
       xPos = append(xPos, x);
       yPos = append(yPos, y);
       dia = append(dia, argDia);
    }
 
void bounce(){
    for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
    ellipse(xPos[i], yPos[i], 50, 50);
    xPos[i] += xSpeed[i];
    yPos[i] += ySpeed[i];
    if(xPos[i]<0 || xPos[i]>=width){
        xSpeed[i] = -xSpeed[i]; 
    }
    
    if(yPos[i]<0 || yPos[i]>=height){
        ySpeed[i] = -ySpeed[i];
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the confusion comes from the fact that your class has two constructors:

- an empty constructor (that takes no arguments): `Ball()`
- a constructor with position and `argDia` (guessing diameter ?) arguments: `Ball(float x, float y, float argDia)`

In `setup()` you call the empty constructor:

```
ball1 = new Ball();
```

This means the five float arrays still have a `length` of 0, hence the out of bounds exception.

Even if you call the position + diameter version of the constructor, the `xSpeed`, `ySpeed` arrays will still have `length` 0.

You could fix this by initialising the two two arrays as well as using this version of the constructor:

```
Ball ball1;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);

  //ball1 = new Ball();
  ball1 = new Ball(250, 250, 50);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  ball1.bounce();
}

class Ball {
  float [] xPos = {};
  float [] yPos = {};
  float [] dia = {};
  float [] xSpeed = {};
  float [] ySpeed = {};

  Ball() {
  }

  Ball(float x, float y, float argDia) {
    xPos = append(xPos, x);
    yPos = append(yPos, y);
    dia = append(dia, argDia);
    xSpeed = append(xSpeed, random(-1, 1));
    ySpeed = append(ySpeed, random(-1, 1));
  }

  void bounce() {
    for (int i=0; i<1; i++) {
      ellipse(xPos[i], yPos[i], 50, 50);
      xPos[i] += xSpeed[i];
      yPos[i] += ySpeed[i];
      if (xPos[i]<0 || xPos[i]>=width) {
        xSpeed[i] = -xSpeed[i];
      }

      if (yPos[i]<0 || yPos[i]>=height) {
        ySpeed[i] = -ySpeed[i];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will work, however there is still a bit of confusion: why use the arrays at all if you're only looping once for the first element ? It makes the arrays and for loop mostly redundant.

You might choose to keep if you plan to change the diameter over time (which in your code is hardcoded to `50`), maybe positions and velocities and render a changing history of a ball.

If you don't, you could simply use `float` properties instead of arrays:

```
Ball ball1;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);

  ball1 = new Ball();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  ball1.bounce();
}

class Ball {
  float xPos;
  float yPos;
  float diameter = 50;
  float xSpeed;
  float ySpeed;

  Ball() {
    xPos = width / 2;
    yPos = height / 2;
    xSpeed = random(-1, 1);
    ySpeed = random(-1, 1);
  }

  void bounce() {
    ellipse(xPos, yPos, diameter, diameter);
    xPos += xSpeed;
    yPos += ySpeed;

    if (xPos < 0 || xPos >= width) {
      xSpeed = -xSpeed;
    }

    if (yPos < 0 || yPos >= height) {
      ySpeed = -ySpeed;
    }
  }
}
```

This looks more similar to the [Bounce Processing Example](https://processing.org/examples/bounce.html).
You can at a later stage make an array of `Ball` objects.

Additionally it's worth formatting code as it saves you time reading/scrolling through it and visually it's easier to scan the structure of the program (how each part fits in) and therefore makes it easier to debug/run mentally. It takes no effort as you can simply press `Ctrl+T` on Windows/Linux or `CMD+T` on OSX. On the long run this will pay off, especially as programs get longer and more complex as you spend more time reading code than writing code. It's a good habit to pickup early while learning to code. Have fun!